# A switch statement without case: or default: labels

Tags: c++, switch-statement, control-flow

cppreference.com [stats](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) that the form of the switch statement is:
`attr switch ( condition ) statement`
and that `statement` is **any** statement.

So, what will happen if I didn't put any `case:` or `default:` labels in `statement`, as:
`switch (1) {std::cout << 'x';}`

What if I wrap a statement that doesn't come after any `case:` or `default:` label with additional braces as:
`switch (1) {{std::cout << 'x';}}`
since wrapping a declaration of a variable with additional braces will make that declaration legal even if it was before every `case:` and `default:` labels.

Comment: You ask two unrelated questions here. Please narrow posts to one issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens.

> [`[stmt.switch/5]:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#5) **When the `switch` statement is executed, its condition is evaluated.** If one of the case constants has the same value as the condition, control is passed to the statement following the matched case label. If no case constant matches the condition, and if there is a default label, control passes to the statement labeled by the `default` label. **If no case matches and if there is no `default` then none of the statements in the switch is executed.**

You didn't label any of your statements with a `case` label, so none of them is labelled by a `case` label that matches the condition, so no statement is executed.

Remember: labels aren't flow constructs that go between statements: they're annotations *for* statements. In the case of `switch` and `goto`, they're merely places to jump to. That's it.

Though the common pattern and typesetting of a `switch`/`case` example has found place in convention and in textbooks, there's nothing in the language grammar that means you *have* to write them that way.

**`switch` is just a conditional `goto` with an optional fallback ("default") case.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the grammar allows any *statements* inside a `switch` statement. So the following snippet:

```
switch( /* condition */ ) 
{
  std::cout << "hello";
}
```

is perfectly valid, although useless, since statements inside a `switch` not preceded by a `case` or `default` label will never get executed.

---

As mentioned in the question, adding a scope inside a `switch` statement *is* needed if you want to declare a variable. However, this doesn't affect the above point. The following snippet:

```
switch( /* condition */ ) 
{
  {
    std::cout << "hello";
  }
}
```

doesn't execute the `cout` statement either.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. Can you answer the additional part that I have added?

Comment: @cigien: There is an exception: loops can _loop_ back into the code before the first case. Aka [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), which can work wonders in micro-optimizations in some cases.

Comment: @MooingDuck No, AFAIK there is no way to get control to go to a statement before a case label in a `switch`. Duff's device doesn't do that either.

Comment: @cigien http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39f7e7ee47388cf6. Duff's device does indeed loop to before the first case. It's merely that the normal form of Duff's device doesn't put code there.

Comment: @MooingDuck Wow, I had no idea that was possible. You taught me something today, thank you very much :)

Comment: @cigien: The insight for me was: `switch` is just pretty-print for `goto`.  I should find out if this works in Java